# Android Studio: How to slide between screens? (Kotlin)

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to do my first app and one of the things that i'm triying is to change between different screens when someone slides the screen with the finger. But i'm just new at this and i don't really know how to do this.
Could anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

PS: I'm using Kotlin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use a `ViewPager` and either `BottomNavigationView` `NavigationView` or `ActionBar`.. Then you will use `Fragment`s and `Activity`s that contain code to handle the individual parts of your app.

The `ViewPager` is what gives the swipeability and then you probably want tabs of some type so the user knows which tab they're on.  The `BottomNavigationView` and `NavigationView` are how you display tabs.  I've got examples in my profile (and a finished project on github) but I use Xamarin.Android not kotlin.

This appears to be a good tutorial on how to do it in Kotlin:

https://tutorialwing.com/android-viewpager-using-kotlin-with-fragment/

It's too much to type out on here.